# Is there a way to get pixel color in Inkscape using command-line or within extension

Tags: svg, inkscape

So lets say there is some SVG file which might have some bitmap objects as well. What i need is some way to detrmine the color of pixel with coordinates X, Y. Basicly same what "dropper tool" does but calling it from command line or from inkscape python extension.

Comment: Ever found a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inkscape binary to export an image, and then use a scripting language (such as PHP) to do the sampling:

```
inkscape --without-gui --export-png=myfile.png --export-dpi=100 myfile.svg
```

If you don't set the DPI it defaults to 90.

I imagine you can also do this in a Python extension, but I can't help there - but there's probably docs for that.